# S3: How to grant public write access to an existing bucket file, but not the putObject permission (Private CRUD, Public Read/Update)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, aws-policies

So, I want to have a service that creates files in an S3 bucket with specific links, and then allow anyone with a link to a file to write to the file and read it.

But it must not be a public privilege to create files, only editing/reading already existing files, given you have the link.

Is this possible with a bucket policy? Basically allowing one service CRUD privileges but having public RU privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write such a service yourself.

First, please note that there is **no difference between 'Create' and 'Update'** in Amazon S3 -- both use a `PutObject` operation. Objects cannot be 'edited' -- they can only be overwritten.

You can achieve your goal for Reading, by using **public objects with obfuscated URLs** -- as long as somebody knows the URL, they could access the object. Not a perfect means of security, but that is your choice.

**You do not want to grant public permission to create objects in a bucket**, otherwise anybody would be able to upload any files to the bucket (eg copyrighted movies) and you would be paying the cost of storage and data transfer.

The safer way to permit uploads is to have users **authenticate to your back-end**, and then your back-end can **generate an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL** that can be used to upload to the bucket. This pre-signed URL can specify limitations such as file size and the filename of the upload.

For more details, see: [Uploading objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Comment: Thanks, this was also my conclusion after reading further. Thank you for a great answer!